# sonar and fortify integration

Tags: sonarqube, fortify

when running the uncompress command from this page:
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Fortify+Plugin 
I get the following error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonar/fortify/uncompress/CLI
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonar.fortify.uncompress.CLI
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    Could not find the main class: org.sonar.fortify.uncompress.CLI.  Program will exit.
```

Has anyone else seen this issue and know how to get around it?  I emailed fortify support about how to uncompress their bin files as well and they seemed surprised about this integration.  any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I was missing this in my plugins directory:  rulepack-uncompress-2.0.jar